# Perform an action on Observable zip subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have the following two functions in Angular 6:

```
http1() {
    return this.http.post<any>('/url1').subscribe(() => console.log(1));
}

http2() {
    return this.http.post<any>('/url2').subscribe(() => console.log(2));
}
```

Now, I want to subscribe to both Observables with zip, and perform an action on completion of both:

```
Observable.zip([http1(), http2()]).subscribe(() => console.log(3));
```

In this example, `3` is not printed in the console, only `1`, and `2`. I need the three of them to be printed, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the `Observable` data from those `http` requests instead of `subscribing` there

```
http1() {
    return this.http.post<any>('/url1').pipe(tap(val => console.log(1)));
}

http2() {
    return this.http.post<any>('/url2').pipe(tap(val => console.log(1)));
}
```

And those `observables` should not be wrapped in an `array`, instead they should be parameters.

```
zip(http1(), http2()).subscribe(() => console.log(3));
```

Comment: zip only works for me as an array, are you using Angular 6?

Comment: Which version of rxjs do you use?

Comment: the one that comes with Angular 6, rxjs 6

Comment: Are you applying spread operator `...` on an array by any chance?

Comment: When I applied your solution I didn't specify an array and it worked. Not sure what happened.

Answer (score 0):

You wrapped the http1 and http2 into a array. This is not how zip works. You have to do this:

```
Observable.zip(http1(), http2()).subscribe(() => console.log(3));
```

**Info:**
see also: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html

Comment: It works for me as an array. How to make the three `console.log` work?

Comment: It worked because you are calling http1 and http2. But zip is not working how you did it. When you remove the array and pass the http `s one by one then it will work.